# Paper size of 8.25in wide by 11in high in Memoir class

Tags: memoir, layout, page

**Question:** How do set the paper/trim size to 8.25in wide by 11in high when using the Memoir class?

**Problem:** I'm publishing a book through Amazon and this is the trim size needed for it.

I have already typeset the book using the following preamble:

```
\documentclass[fleqn,12pt]{memoir}
\pagestyle{headings}
\setlength{\headheight}{14.5pt}
\usepackage{calc}

\makeevenhead{headings}{}{}{Some Heading}
\makeoddhead{headings}{Some Heading}{}{}
\makeevenfoot{headings}{}{}{\thepage}
\makeoddfoot{headings}{\thepage}{}{}

\usepackage{graphicx}
\usepackage{caption}
\usepackage{subcaption}
\usepackage{rotating}
\usepackage{microtype}
\usepackage{booktabs}

\addtolength{\oddsidemargin}{-.875in}
\addtolength{\evensidemargin}{-.875in}
\addtolength{\textwidth}{1.75in}

\addtolength{\topmargin}{-.875in}
\addtolength{\textheight}{1.75in}
```

Comment: Memoir has macros `\setstocksize`, `\settrimmedsize` and `\settypeblocksize`. The first is used to set the length and width of the paper on which the book is to be printed, the second sets the trimmed size of the eventual bound book, and the third sets the size of the body text (excluding headers, footers, marginnotes and such).

Comment: @WillieWong In my case I only know that the trim size is supposed to be 8.25 x 11.  In that case I think using `\settrimmedsize` would be sufficient, right?

Comment: @WillieWong In the answer you linked I don't see how the 15mm for the margin was calculated to see how to adapt it to my case.

Comment: The linked answer sets a 15mm smaller trimmed width than the stock size because that was what was originally specified by the OP (a stock size that is 210mm wide and a trimmed size that is 195mm wide). Whether you should prepare the document to have a different stock size and trim size is a question you need to ask Amazon (or your publisher) and not us, since this depends on the printing process. // As to how to make it work with your case: [memoir has one of the most comprehensive manuals in existence](https://ctan.org/pkg/memoir?lang=en), please read Chapter 2 there.